# Illuminate\Contracts\Filesystem\FileNotFoundException in Laravel 5.6 using Storage facade

Tags: laravel, linux-mint

This code is returning an strange error:

```php
$file = Storage::get(Storage::disk('notas_xml')->path('') . 't.txt');
```

[image]

As you can see the file does exist.

Answer (score 2):

Get the file directly from the disk

```php
$exists = Storage::disk('notas_xml')->exists('t.txt');
if ($exists) {
  $file = Storage::disk('notas_xml')->get('t.txt');
}
```

And if you didn't setup `notas_xml` disk in `filesystems.php`

```php
$file = Storage::get('public/arquivos/notas_xml/t.txt');
```

And to use your code, you need to setup a disk like so in `config/filesystems.php`

```php
'notas_xml' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => storage_path('app/public/arquivos/notas_xml'),
    'url' => env('APP_URL') . '/storage',
    'visibility' => 'public',
],
```

And get the file simply like this

```php
$file = Storage::disk('notas_xml')->get('t.txt');
```

Comment: I performed all the steps. The error makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the file as below code:

```
Storage::disk('notas_xml')->has('t.txt');
```

Above `has` method may be used to determine if a given file exists on the disk:

Please read documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/filesystem#retrieving-files

Answer (score 1):

To better understand all this... The trick is in: `config/filesystems.php` 
If you have this code (which is the default value of Laravel in Github)

```
    'disks' => [
        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
        ],
```

This Facade `Storage` will act in the folders

> root_laravel_project/storage/app

So if you want to check if an "israel.txt" file exists 
`if( Storage::exists('israel.txt') ){ 
   echo "File found. And it exists on the path: root_laravel_project/storage/app/israel.txt";
}`

Remember that up to this point it has nothing to do with the symbolic link `php artisan storage: link`

This symbolic link is only to make a folder called "public" within the "storage" folder be part of the public access through HTTP

```
    'disks' => [
        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
        ],
        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
```

Then at the time of doing the sym. You can access the files by http (which are public for any user)
*This example assumes that you are using a virtual host (and if not, you must do it as a recommendation for work better locally)*

> http:// root_laravel_project.test/storage/israel-alvarez.txt

Or so that it is better understood as in the old school without a virtual host

> http:// localhost/public/storage/israel-alvarez.txt

Then these urls will look inside your folder

> root_laravel_project/storage/app/public/israel-alvarez.txt

Laravel's documentation is somewhat brief and can be confusing regarding this issue. But you just have to remember that one thing is to access through the "storage Facade" (which is the correct way to upload and verify if there are files) and another thing is to access through the http (through url) which is the symbolic link (which is the treatment you already give to users to download files or see if it is a PDF for example).

I hope it helps. Good day